# g2o c++ library difficulty in understanding the logic

Tags: c++, c, arm

I am a student and beginner in C. I need to optimise the cholesky factorisation used in the file at

https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/g2o/solvers/csparse/csparse_helper.cpp

for ARM using vectorization and using the Ne10 library.

But I am having difficulty in understanding the logic of the function cs_chol_workspace. The function is returning a pointer variable N which is not at all changed within the function. Also even though I understand that variable L represents the factorised matrix, what is Lx,Li and Lp ? The logic is far more complicated than my level of understanding.

I have been trying to understand the code for past few days. Any help will be extremely appreciable as I am approaching my deadline and still with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> The function is returning a pointer variable N which is not at all changed within the function.

Not true.  Memory is allocated for a `csn`, and its address assigned to `N` at line 96.

> Also even though I understand that variable L represents the factorised matrix, what is Lx,Li and Lp ?

The important part to understand this is how are we storing the matrix.  The standard way to store a matrix is by allocating enough memory to store all `m * n` entries, and access them as `L_non_sparse[i][p]`.  In this case, the data structure is designed to hold sparse matrices:  i.e. most of the entries are 0.  So, we only need to keep track of where the non-zero entries are.  In line 107, `Lx`, `Li`, and `Lp` are defined as the `x`, `i`, and `p` components of `L`.  So we access the non-zero entries of `L_non_sparse` by `L_non_sparse[ Li[j] ][ Lp[j] ] = Lx[j]`.

This is based off of the definitions in [cs.h](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/EXTERNAL/csparse/cs.h)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can u explain what it means by the x i and p part of a matrix a bit more. If I am getting it correctly, i and p are the two coordinates of the 2 dimensional matrix. Is (Li(j),Lp(j)) holding the coordinates of the value Lx(j) in the matrix?

Comment: That was the way that I read the definition of a `csn` in the header file.